# How to get twitter cosumer_key and consumer_secret

Tags: java, access-token, twitter4j

Working on a java project and I want to get access tokens with usernames and passwords.

But for the access tokens I need the consumer_key and the consumer_secret.

I already created my application at [Twitter Apps](https://dev.twitter.com/apps) and have a access token for my own account.

Im using the library Twitter 4J.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate these keys on the "Keys and Access Tokens" tab of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Consumer Key (API Key) and Consumer Secret (API Secret) are in the key and access tokens tab in your application , if there is no key in your application setting, you should first "generate consumer key and secret".